# Once I'm logged in how can I send an authenticated POST request?

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

One more question:

I built a simply script where I use XmlHttpRequest to login to a server like this:

```
var requestUrl = 'https://www.testsite.com/engine2/api/Login';

xmlhttp.open('POST', requestUrl, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;


    xmlhttp.send("username=myusername&password=mypassword&grant_type=password");

    }
```

I'm able to login and I receive a 200: true http status response. Now that I'm logged in I'd like to send the following POST request:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var requestUrlCreate = 'https://www.testsite.com/engine2/api/channel/47377/post/publish';
xmlhttp.open('POST', requestUrlCreate, true);

xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

My problem is that this last request returns error 403 (Forbidden) as if it was not authenticated. I think I'm missing something basic (maybe should I store session credentials in a  cookie?).
Could you please let me know? Thank you!

Comment: You can't set cookies across domains.

Comment: testsite.com != beabloo.com why would logging into testsite get you access to beabloo?

Comment: Sorry, it was  a mistake, I fixed it, the domain is the same, which is testsite.com please let me know, thank you!

Comment: you generally get access token in login response which you have to store and send during each and every new request in header generally.

Comment: Thanks but the API doesn't return me with a token, I'm returned with a "status 200 - response: true" and therefore I don't know how to authenticate the following POST requests, do I have to send credentials in every request? Thanks for helping!